# Does dual-source blending require larger color buffer?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

In OpenGL, we can turn on dual-source blending through following code in fragment shader:

```
layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 color1;
layout(location = 0, index = 1) out vec4 color2;
```

And through token XX_SRC1_XX get color2 in blending functions. I have questions that:

1. If I want to do off-screen rendering, do I need to double the texture's storage's size as there are two colors output.
2. Is it that once I turn on dual-source blending then I can only output two colors to one buffer? And it means that I cannot bind more than one color buffers through attaching them to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi tokens.
3. Is the qualifier 'index' here only used for dual-source blending purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Dual-source blending means blending involving two color outputs from the FS. That has *nothing* to do with the nature of the images being written to (only the number). Location 0 still refers to the [0th index in the `glDrawBuffers` array](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers), and the attachment works just as it did previously.

You are outputting two colors. But only one value (the result of the blend operation) gets written.

> And it means that I cannot bind more than one color buffers through attaching them to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` tokens.

Well, that depends on the number of attached images allowed when [doing dual-source blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending#Dual_Source_Blending), as specified by your implementation. Granted, [all known implementations set this to 1](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displaycapability.php?name=GL_MAX_DUAL_SOURCE_DRAW_BUFFERS). Even Vulkan implementations all use 1 (or 0 if they don't support dual-source blending); the only ones that don't [seem to be either early, broken implementations or software renderers](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displaydevicelimit.php?name=maxFragmentDualSrcAttachments&platform=all),